# What is the best way to store data locally in iOS app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm building a workout app for iOS. It's more of an app for myself to learn how to make iOS apps.
I was wondering what the best way is to store the workouts.

I was thinking about just putting all the different workouts in a database and retrieving them from the database but if your gym doesn't have good internet you might not even be able to retrieve any workouts.

I'm guessing I have to store them locally then but I was just wondering what the best way to do that is. I'm planning on adding hundreds, maybe thousands of workouts to the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can use core data.  Do a google search for swift core data tutorials.